# Create a new table row/user on click php, ajax, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

The html, and clicking the create div would redirect to an identical page, but would add a new row and increment the `[text_edit_id]` in the database. This is my table: http://imgur.com/KoNg1ju

```
<div class="saveChange" onclick="saveEdits()"></div>
<div class="cancelChange" onclick="cancelEdits()"></div>
<div class="create"></div>

<div id="edit" class="title textEditor">
    <span contenteditable="true" class="pageTitle one editable" id="bodyTitle"><?php echo $row['text_title']; ?></span>
    <p id="bodyText" class="editable" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['text_text']; ?></p>
</div>
```

When you save a change

```
function saveEdits() {
var title = $('.pageTitle').html();
var text = $('#bodyText').html();
    console.log(title + text);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "functions/functions.php",
      data: { title: title, text: text }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
};
```

the functions.php

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$db = "textedit";

$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$text_title = $_POST['title'];
$text_text = $_POST['text'];

$stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE data SET text_title = ?, text_text = ? WHERE text_edit_id = 1");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $text_title, $text_text);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Ok great. So what's your question?

Comment: apologies for not being clear, but my question is how to add a new row in the database when I click 'create' div, having the [text_edit_id] increment. I'm sorry if this isn't clear, I'm an early beginner with php/ajax/mysql and this is as far as I could get with tutorials. @Madbreaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you managed to add new records in your mysql database, but the problem is that you want the field "text_edit_id" to increment automatically... then the solution is very simple:

In phpmyadmin define the "text_edit_id" as described:

- type integer
- autoincrement (flag the checkbox - this option must be selected)

Text_edit_id should be the "primary key" of the table.

You can modify all these parameters in the "structure" section of your table. It's very easy.

This way, when you save a new record into the database, the "text_edit_id" value will be generated automatically and will be equal to "last value +1".

```
text_edit_id    text_title    text_text
     1          First news   News content
     2          Second news  Other content
```

IMPORTANT
Note that if you want to ADD a new row in your table (like shown above) your query is wrong.

```
  $stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE data SET text_title = ?, text_text = ? WHERE text_edit_id = 1");
```

This means: "Update the table record where "text_id_field" equlas to 1 with the new values for "text_title" and "text_text". 
Of course the text_edit_id isn't changed!!

What you are looking for is the INSERT STATMENT. This way, each time a NEW line (= a new record) will be created with an autoincrementing index.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO data (text_title, text_text) VALUES (?,?) ");
```

Substitute this line to the one in your script.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. I have it set to both integer and a.i.. What I'm trying to wrap my head around is having it increment when I click the create button. From what I've seen online so far, I would need another ajax function like I do for saveEdits(); and I've created a create_new.php I'm just lost in the actual php code to add to the text_edit_id. @IgorCarmagna

Comment: Is the text_edit_field marked as the primary key of that table? You can check this clicking on the table name. See this image: http://i454.photobucket.com/albums/qq270/gagawagabaga/1.png

Comment: Ok.. I think I've found the problem... wait a few seconds

Comment: It's just the query that is wrong.. it UPDATES the row with id = 1 and changes the text_title and the text_text with the new values. Do you want to generate a NEW row (leaving the one already present in the table unchanged) or do you want to always keep 1 row in the table and just update its content?

Comment: Okay, so here is the link so you can see: http://trevormsmith.com/textedit/index.php, what you see is id = 1, and I want to keep that. It would be the testing page where anyone can change the content. In the upper right there will be a button to create your own where only they would be able to edit the content, so from there it would increment up. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: "a button to create your own (what?? missing word) where only they would be (able??) to edit...". Honestly it is not very clear, but at least I get what your page does now

Comment: Will the new button create a new box where the users can change the content and save it? I mean a second box, and then a third box etc

Comment: A button to create their own page, the exact same setup as index.php, only it would be id = 2 and so on.

Comment: Great.. now I get it. So what you need to do is change the query from and UPDATE query to and INSERT query like shown in the post (look up.. I updated it). Each new page will have its own record in the table (that means each page = one row).

Comment: I wrote the new code in the answer. Try it. If it works mark the answer as the righ one

Comment: Of course you will create an UPDATE button (which fires an UPDATE query) and a ADD NEW button (which fires an INSERT query).

Comment: Okay, I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around this. So I add that line into the functions.php? And that would still keep the first id = 1 editable? Or do i need another separate function which is triggered when clicked, and have the INSERT line in there? Could you expand a little more or could we possibly go into chat?

Comment: okay so when you click it creates another row: http://imgur.com/w2vaqHu, awesome, so now I would just need to add a redirect when clicked going to a new page, and if you make an edit it will edit that id's content and not revert back to id = 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66689/discussion-between-igor-carmagna-and-trev).